# visualizing inner joins with three tables

Tags: sql, join

Can someone explain the difference between these 2 types of joins and  how to visualize them? Not sure when to use which...

Ex1

```
select a.f1, a.f2, b.f1, b.f2
from table_a a
inner join table_c c
    on a.id = c.id
inner join table_b b
    on c.id = b.id
```

Ex 2

```
SELECT a.au_lname,
       a.au_fname,
       t.title
FROM   authors a
       INNER JOIN titleauthor ta
         ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
       JOIN titles t
         ON ta.title_id = t.title_id
WHERE  t.type = 'trad_cook'
ORDER  BY t.title ASC
```

Using this unrelated venn diagram- what do these 2 queries return?

[image]

Comment: If you mean difference between `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN`, there are no difference.

Comment: I don't see any significant difference in your two examples.

Comment: What is the difference between a duck? One of its legs are both the same!

Comment: The second query limits the result to rows with `t.type = 'trad_cook'` whereas the first query does not have a `where` clause at all. Apart from that there is no real difference.

Comment: okay thank you. using the venn diagram above what portion of the diagram am i returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that you are joining three tables in your `SELECT` statement.

- `authors` is joined with `titleauthor`
- `titleauthor` is joined with `titles`

To learn more about joins, please see the article below,

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: I get it with 2 tables, not 3 though... what does the join look like in the 3 case?

Comment: @nivyaj - Both of the examples you posted join 3 tables.

Comment: @nivyaj then what are these: `authors`, `titleauthor`, and `titles`?

Comment: sorry i get the visualization with 2 tables, not 3 though. Can you take a look at the venn diagram i added and explain the join in that context?

Comment: @nivyaj - So it would be nerd in the case of your Venn diagram as it is the intersection of all three tables although TBH using Venn diagrams to visualise joins is a flawed concept.

Comment: flawed because it assumes unique records only, right? or is there another reason?

Comment: Because it assumes unique records and also because it can't represent key concepts such as cross joins and non equi joins and can also cause additional confusion as in  [the question posed here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13997365/73226)