# Merge two trees on equal nodes

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, tree

Nodes are equal when their IDs are equal. IDs in one tree are unique. On the schemas, IDs of nodes are visible.

Consider `tree1`:

```
root
  |
  +-- CC
  |   |
  |   \-- ZZZ
  |        |
  |        \-- UU
  |
  \-- A
      |
      \-- HAH
```

And `tree2`:

```
root
  |
  +-- A
      |
      +-- ADD
      |
      \-- HAH
```

I would like that `merge(tree1, tree2)` will give this:

```
root
  |
  +-- CC
  |   |
  |   \-- ZZZ
  |        |
  |        \-- UU
  |
  \-- A
      |
      +-- HAH
      |
      \-- ADD
```

How to do it?

Node has typical methods like `getParent()`, `getChildren()`.

Order of the children doesn't matter. So, the result could be also:

```
root
  |
  +-- A
  |   |
  |   +-- ADD
  |   |
  |   \-- HAH
  |
  \-- CC
     |
     \-- ZZZ
          |
          \-- UU
```

Comment: If nodes are unordered, I see no alternative but to select one tree as the survivor then iterate over the other tree and add nodes from it to the first tree that don't already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proposition in pseudocode. Comments are more than welcome.

```
merge(tree1, tree2) {
    for (node : tree2.bfs()) { // for every node in breadth-first traversal order
        found = tree1.find(node.getParent());     // find parent in tree1
        if (found == null)                        // no parent?
            continue;                             // skip it, it's root
        if (!found.getChildren().contains(node))  // no node from tree2 in tree1?
            found.add(node);                      // add it
    }
    return tree1;
}
```

Comment: I have same question. Is it possible to do that in SQL directly? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram (full outer join)

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm is not hard:

```
def merge_trees (t1, t2):
  make_tree(map(merge_trees,assign(getChildren(t1),getChildren(t2),tree_similarity)))
```

- `make_tree(children)`: create a tree with the given list of children
- `map(f,list)`: calls function `f` on each element of `list` and return the list of return values
- `assign(list1,list2,cost_function)`: implements the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), returning the list of matched pairs

The trick is in defining `tree_similarity` which would have to call `assign` recursively.

In fact, the efficient implementation would have to cache the return values of the `assign` calls.