# Mysql left join style sum()

Tags: mysql, sql

I believe the answer is already there at stackoverflow but I cannot find the right keywords. So please help.

Table **sales** looks like this:

```
state  | sales-representative        | product | sales
NY     | Mike B.                     | prod-A  | 90
FL     | David J.                    | prod-B  | 120 
FL     | Mike B.                     | prod-A  | 15
```

I need to get the total sales by such sales representative. Expected results for Mike B. look at this:

```
state  | product | sales
NY     | prod-A  | 90
FL     | prod-A  | 15
NY     | prod-B  | 0 <--How can I get this record as well?
FL     | prod-B  | 0
```

A regular sum query returns the first 2 records. How can I get the last 2 records as well?

```
 select state, product, sum(sales) 
      from sales 
      where sales-representative = 'Mike B.' 
       group by state, product
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Comment: @Sirmyself, so it should be full-join style sum()?

Comment: `left join` should do you good

Comment: You can also see thos venn diagrams to visualise more easily : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram

Comment: So, you want the total sales for a sales representative, for every combination of every product and state that appears anywhere in the table?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ss.state, sp.product, SUM(sr.sales)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT state FROM sales) AS ss
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT product FROM sales) AS sp
LEFT JOIN sales AS r  
   AS sr ON ss.state = s.state 
         AND sp.product = s.product
         AND r.`sales-representative` = 'Mike B.'
GROUP BY ss.state, sp.product;
```

The cross join gets you every combination of state and product, and the left join gets you the specified representative's associated sales.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join on subquery for stated  and product

```
   select t.state, t.product, sum(sales)
   from table1 
   left join (
    select t1.state, t2.product
    from t1 
    cross join  (
        select product 
        from t1
    ) t2

   ) t on t.state = table1.state and t.product = table1.product
   grooup by t.state, t.product
```