# Condition on main table in inner join vs in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, where-clause

Is there any reason on an `INNER JOIN` to have a condition on the main table vs in the `WHERE` clause?

Example in `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
   (various columns here from each table)
FROM dbo.MainTable AS m
INNER JOIN dbo.JohnDataRecord AS jdr
    ON m.ibID = jdr.ibID
    AND m.MainID = @MainId -- question here
    AND jdr.SentDate IS NULL
LEFT JOIN dbo.PTable AS p1
    ON jdr.RecordID = p1.RecordID
LEFT JOIN dbo.DataRecipient AS dr
    ON jdr.RecipientID = dr.RecipientID
(more left joins here)
WHERE
    dr.lastRecordID IS NOT NULL;
```

Query with condition in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
   (various columns here from each table)
FROM dbo.MainTable AS m
INNER JOIN dbo.JohnDataRecord AS jdr
    ON m.ibID = jdr.ibID
    AND jdr.SentDate IS NULL
LEFT JOIN dbo.PTable AS p1
    ON jdr.RecordID = p1.RecordID
LEFT JOIN dbo.DataRecipient AS dr
    ON jdr.RecipientID = dr.RecipientID
(more left joins here)
WHERE
    m.MainID = @MainId -- question here
    AND dr.lastRecordID IS NOT NULL;
```

Difference in other similar questions that are more general whereas this is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: For an inner join, it is just a matter of style.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what I thought but sometimes I don't know everything hence why I asked.  I find the first "style" to be less clear to me.

Comment: @Mark You and me both. It's an odd place to stick the condition. Totally valid, but totally odd.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097 Anyway this is a duplicate/faq, google your title, see [ask] & read the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Comment: @philipxy - agree it is generally the same subject however that other question is just that (general) and not specific to SQL SERVER and version.

Comment: Do you think you are the first person to ask this? (Rhetorical.) Beware of a lot of highly-upvoted nonsense posts on SQL semantics https://stackoverflow.com/a/25957600/3404097 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join?rq=1#comment41531068_38549 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment85420636_6188334 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram#comment51529331_13997365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scope of the question,

> Is there any reason on an INNER JOIN to have a condition on the main
>   table vs in the WHERE clause?

**This is a STYLE choice for the INNER JOIN.**

---

### From a pure style reflection point of view:

While there is no hard and fast rule for STYLE, it is generally observed that this is a less often used style choice.  For example that might generally lead to more challenging maintenance such as if someone where to remove the `INNER JOIN` and all the subsequent `ON` clause conditions, it would effect the primary table result set, OR make the query more difficult to debug/understand when it is a very complex set of joins.

It might also be noted that this line might be placed on many INNER JOINS further adding to the confusion.