# Get all values from Table1 and get one field's value from Table 2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Table 1 and table 2

I would like to get all the data from Table1 and one column's value from table 2.

Unique details for both tables are the mobile number.

So I tried this:

```
SELECT d.*, a.paymentmode FROM table1 d JOIN table2 a ON d.user = a.mobile WHERE a.mobile = '+911234567890'
```

I get double results.

Like: For the above mobile number.

Order1

Order1

Order2

Order2

Order3

Order3

Order4

Order4

[image]

What is the issue here? How do I show only Order1, Order2, Order3, Order4 instead of double?

Comment: is d.user column has mobile number ?

Comment: Could you please add sample data?

Comment: @UWU_SANDUN: Sorry for the delay. Yes. the mobile number.

Comment: Sample data already added.. but only one column. that is all..

Comment: Added a screenshot of the daya

Comment: anyone? struggling to get the result. :(

Comment: can you please give me a sample data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table 1 user column *is* a mobile number, what you're missing is the type of JOIN

Types of join and their logic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram)

Btw - Another thing I would do is remove all none numeric keys ('+', '-' etc) from the mobile number fields, it can save possible JOI errors etc.

Comment: Didn't understand what are you trying to say? Please explain thanks!

Comment: INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN will give you 2 different answers. please look at the link I added

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use Group by.

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.column_name FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.mobile = t2.mobile WHERE t2.mobile = '+911234567890' GROUP BY t1.mobile
```

Comment: You'll lose cases in that way. Under the assumption that the mobile numbers are unique, no duplicates should appear anyway

Comment: If I use this query I am getting only one record.