# Find all lines where a value exists in one line

Tags: sql-server, select, exists

Here is my query

```
        select order_no, pkg_no, zone_no
        from T_DETAIL_ITEM a 
        where order_no = 495
        order by order_no, pkg_no
```

For a given package I have `zone number = 0`

[image]

What I need to do is return all the lines with the `pkg_no = 1597`. Because one where exists with a zero zone.

I tried a few different 'where exists' lines and it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to self join.
This way you can put your requirement in the second table "instance" but retrieve everything from that table matches based on another common field.

```
select distinct a.order_no, a.pkg_no, a.zone_no
        from T_DETAIL_ITEM a 
        join T_DETAIL_ITEM b on b.pkg_no = a.pkg_no
        where b.zone_no = 0
        order by a.order_no, a.pkg_no
```

Comment: I'm a little lost with one thing, when i pull the zone numbers for table a, i get numbers ... 33, 23, 295 etc. When i do the zone numbers for table b they are all zeros. why is this. This isn't entirely correct here.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR zone numbers will be always zero just because that's what we put in the `WHERE` clause (for b). All other zones number will be fetched since that line contains the same pkg number for one occurrence of a ZERO zone number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good, but I had saw that you noted you tried EXISTS, so I wrote this example up using that method.

```
SELECT *
FROM T_Detail_Item  d
WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM T_Detail_Item  dx WHERE dx.pkg_no = d.pkg_no AND dx.zone_no = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to self reference the table in a left join and only include those with a zone_no=0, within the join clause. The filter out non-matching records by excluding records that do not match from the left join, T2.pkg_no = NULL.

```
SELECT
    T1.pkg_no, T1.zone_no
FROM
    T_DETAIL_ITEM  T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T_DETAIL_ITEM T2 ON T2.pkg_no = T1.pkg_no AND T2.zone_no = 0
WHERE
    NOT T2.pkg_no IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understood the question, you need something like this
BEGIN

```
declare @str varchar(max);

set @str='';

SELECT  @str=@str+ [YOURCOLUMB]

  FROM [YOURTABLE]

SELECT @str

END
```