# Making a query to merge two tables upon criteria, with giving priority to the rows from the second table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, union-all

I’ve got two MS Access tables.

```
table1
ID  Country     Dat         Val
1   Australia   01.10.2021  10
2   Canada      01.10.2021  100
3   Japan       01.10.2021  1000
4   Australia   02.10.2021  20
5   Canada      02.10.2021  200
6   Japan       02.10.2021  2000
```

and

```
table2
ID  Country     Dat         Val
1   Canada      01.10.2021  50000
2   Greece      01.10.2021  50100
3   Canada      02.10.2021  60000
4   Greece      02.10.2021  60100
```

This SQL-code allows me to **merge two tables**, which gives 10 rows.

```
   SELECT table2.Dat,
          table2.Country,
          table2.Val
     FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1
       ON (table1.Dat = table2.Dat)
      AND (table1.Country = table2.Country)

UNION ALL

   SELECT table1.Dat,
          table1.Country,
          table1.Val
     FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
       ON (table1.Dat = table2.Dat)
      AND (table1.Country = table2.Country)

 ORDER BY table2.Dat,
          table2.Country;
```

And it gives duplicates based on "Date" and "Country" criteria.

**The question**

I wonder, what should the code look like if I would like to merge two tables in a way that, if table1 and table2 have the same "Date" and "Country", then table2 rows would be chosen, not both?

In other words, how to take **all unique rows from table1 and table2** that **doesn’t match** criteria "Date" AND "Country", as well as give **precedence to table2** **when** rows in two tables **match** the criteria "Date" AND "Country"?

(A "Date + Country" bundle is unique within each table, i.e. there is only one "Data + Country" within one table)

In other words, what query could I use to make the result **look like this**, i.e. 8 rows without date + country duplicates?

```
Expected Result
Dat         Country     Val
01.10.2021  Australia   10
01.10.2021  Canada      50000
01.10.2021  Greece      50100
01.10.2021  Japan       1000
02.10.2021  Australia   20
02.10.2021  Canada      60000
02.10.2021  Greece      60100
02.10.2021  Japan       2000
```

And what might be a good **way to make** such SQL-scripts to merge tables based upon several criteria like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `UNION ALL` for the 2 tables and use `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause for `table1`:

```
SELECT t1.Dat, t1.Country,  t1.Val FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.Country = t1.Country AND t2.Dat = t1.Dat)
UNION ALL
SELECT Dat, Country, Val FROM table2
ORDER BY Dat, Country
```

Results:

```
Dat         Country     Val
1/10/2021   Australia   10
1/10/2021   Canada      50000
1/10/2021   Greece      50100
1/10/2021   japan       1000
2/10/2021   Australia   20
2/10/2021   Canada      60000
2/10/2021   Greece      60100
2/10/2021   Japan       2000
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic way is just to split such tasks into sub-tasks.

The smaller, thus easier, sub-tasks here could be the following:

1. Get all rows (matching the criteria "Date" and "Country") which ***exist in table2***, but are ***absent in table1***.
2. Get all rows (matching the criteria "Date" and "Country") which ***exist in table1***, but are ***absent in table2***.
3. Get all rows (matching the criteria "Date" and "Country") which ***exist in both*** table2 and table1, but taking rows ***only from table2***.
4. Put ***UNION ALL*** ***in between the parts*** you’ve previously created and tested (to make sure everything works properly).

Therefore, here is a possible strightforward solution:

```
   SELECT table2.Dat,
          table2.Country,
          table2.Val
     FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1
       ON (table1.Country = table2.Country)
      AND (table1.Dat = table2.Dat)
    WHERE table1.Country IS NULL
      AND "comment: Getting from table2 everything that is absent in table1 (matching country and date criteria)"

UNION ALL

   SELECT table1.Dat,
          table1.Country,
          table1.Val
     FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
       ON (table1.Country = table2.Country)
      AND (table1.Dat = table2.Dat)
    WHERE table2.Country IS NULL
      AND "comment: Getting from table1 everything that is absent in table2 (matching country and date criteria)"

UNION ALL

   SELECT table2.Dat,
          table2.Country,
          table2.Val
     FROM table2,
          table1
    WHERE table1.Country = table2.Country
      AND table1.Dat = table2.Dat
      AND "comment: getting from table2 everything that exists in table1 (matching country and date criteria)"

 ORDER BY table2.Dat,
          table2.Country;
```

**Conclusion**

So the problem here is just to take the corresponding rows from "overlapping sets", and then merging them.

To undestand a bit more, you might have a look at [Venn diagram and some other answers here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram) or [non-Venn way explanation here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/).

Comment: 3 subqueries is excess. **All** from table2 + from table1 which not exists in table2 - this is enough.

Comment: @akina, Well, each subquery written here could be used as separate scripts, for others to use... But on the other hand you might be right, two subqueries might be a bit faster here...