# Mongo lookup condition: not exist

Tags: mongodb, left-join, pymongo, lookup, aggregation

We have two collections.

One is the **books** collection with loads of data. Like:

```
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01d773faa"},
   'isbn': 8765434567890,
   'booktitle': 'some text',
}
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01d773faa"},
   'isbn': 8765434566666,
   'booktitle': 'other book',
}
```

The **notes** collection has documents with extra info about some of the documents in the base collection. Like:

```
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01d773faa"},
   'isbn': 8765434567890,
   'note': 'blabla',
}
```

So not all documents in **books** have a counterpart in **notes**. If there is, it's **one-to-one**.

What I try to find out is an aggregation that shows all of the **books** documents (with possibly additinal {match} stuff), that specifically **do not have a counterpart** in the **notes** collection.

```
[
   {'$match': {}},
   {'$lookup':
      {
        'from': 'notes',
        'localField': 'isbn',
        'foreignField': 'isbn',
        'as': 'related_note',
      }
   },
   {'$project':
      {
         'isbn': '$isbn',
         'title': '$title',
         'note': '-- no notes about this title',
      }
   }
]
```

So not a left-join, not a right-join but a: NOT(left-join)

Anybody? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I try to find out is an aggregation that shows all of the books documents (with possibly additinal {match} stuff), that specifically do not have a counterpart in the notes collection.*

Would say that your result should be LEFT JOIN but excluding intersection.

[image]

Reference: [SQL joins as Venn diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13997365/8017690)

By default, MongoDB `$lookup` performs as the LEFT JOIN. To exclude the documents which are under the intersection, you can filter with `related_note: []` via the `$match` stage.

```
db.books.aggregate([
  //{
  //  "$match": {}
  //},
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "notes",
      "localField": "isbn",
      "foreignField": "isbn",
      "as": "related_note"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      related_note: []
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "isbn": "$isbn",
      "title": "$title",
      "note": "-- no notes about this title",
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qn0RjTVLeW-)

Comment: If life only was as simple as this. Just ask for nothing and you all wishes come true. Thanks Yong Shun ;-)